# centered HTML timeline structure using CSS? With only the sides scaling?

Tags: html, css, timeline

Okay so I have this structure that I am trying to create with CSS, but all my attempts have not yielded a proper result, I tried searching the internet for help, and found some guides to timeline structures but none of them seemed to do what I am trying to do.

So here is what my basic structure is: [image]

So the idea here is that the window resolution is 1800px in width, and structure is some div container, the light grey background, that is somehow centered either a margin: 0 auto or something else with a set with of 1200px. Then to act as the backbone of the page is the middle red timeline which is centered and will keep the same set width, not a percentage. Around the timeline on the left and right side there will be these tooltip type boxes which will scale in height depending on the amount of text.

Next if you resize the window resolution to something like 1000px in width, therefore smaller than the light grey area. The middle timeline stays the same set width, but the tooltip boxes changes in width and increases in height because of the lack horizontal space, instead it uses the vertical space. 
the tooltip boxes will keep the same distance from the timeline, let's say of 15px, so they sort of have to decrease in width from both sides, and that is where I am running into a wall. 
[image]

The way I imagened it myself was somehow for the timeline to be build out of modules, like shown below, so the tooltips would correspond to a part of the timeline, and then timelines with tooltips would be stacked up on each other. But any solution is appreciated,

[image]

Here is a link to what I have so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWZwGL

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.timezone{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.timezone > div {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.timeline {
  width: 100px;
  background: darkred;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.event_left {
  margin-left: 1%;
  width: calc(49% - 1% - 20px);
  background: #ededed;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}

.event_right {
  width: calc(45% - 1% - 30px);
  background: #ededed;
  margin-left: calc(2% + 40px);
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="timezone">
    <div class="event_left">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
    <div class="timeline">34.000 BNC</div>
    <div class="event_right">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

where I am trying to achieve the tooltip scaling, it's not close to perfect, and the timeline height doesn't even adjust with the tooltip height :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Without posting the code you're tired your question appears as if you're asking us to code this entirely for you.

Comment: No what I am asking, is when we have a centered div, the timeline, with then a left div and a right div on either side of the timeline, when the screen width is scaled in width, how do they automatically scale, with the center div staying put. All the other stuff was to give an idea of where I am going with it, and that might have an influence on what people would answer.

Comment: To paraphrase what I wrote in the text: "the tooltip boxes will keep the same distance from the timeline, let's say of 15px, so they sort of have to decrease in width from both sides, and that is where I am running into a wall." That is my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of the rest of the code, I used some of mine. To explain it briefly, I have centered the "timeline" darkred bar and gave it a 2% width, then positioned the other ones accordingly, having a width of 49% - 1% - 20px where the 20px is the distance to the bar.

The right side has a margin-left of 2% (the width of the bar) + double the distance to the bar (we don't want do disregard the left one's margin)
This is how the calculations look for the right side:

```
    .level .right {
        width: calc(49% - 1% - 20px);
        margin-left: calc(2% + 40px);
        vertical-align:middle;
```

The full codepen can be viewed [here](http://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/qNjWbp). I hope it hepls!

Comment: it's very very very close, the issue is just having a central timeline with a fixed witdth, that was the difficult bit. Something I have been trying to achieve here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWZwGL

Comment: That 2% can be modified in the codepen to any value. You have to replace the 1% in the side width calculation with half of the timeline width, and the 2% in the margin calculation of the right one. See here for a 100px timeline bar example: http://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/ZOyzBL Is this what you meant?

Comment: This is it, amazing, just what I was trying to achieve, thank you so much, and the code is simple when you look through it, really cool. So elegant :)